# ERROR : MySQL server has gone away while running query

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am using ubuntu 12.04 version. I am connecting properly to MariaDB from command prompt,I have a database named Dealer and have some tables in it but when i running any query, it gives an error.My steps as follow:

1. mysql -uroot -proot
2. use dealer;
3. select * from dealer_outlet limit 1;

now error occours

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    3
Current database: dealer

ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
ERROR: Can't connect to the server

Comment: I had this error when I opened a connection and tried to execute a query after a long period of time (after a build had finished). My solution was to open a new connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question lacks lots of detail such as log output, I just throw in a guess.

Have you checked that your MySQL data partition (or `/tmp`, or wherever you have configured MySQL to store temp files) is not full? See with `df -h` and make sure there's disk space left.

Another option is that your `dealer_outlet` table is corrupted and needs to be repaired. Are you able to select from any other table or database without MySQL dying?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MariaDB crashes when you execute your query. You should check the logs from MariaDB. There should be some information about whats happening. Most likely related to some files or paths not being readable or writeable.